# Logarithm Question $\log_{3}9x+\log_{3}x=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

**Edit: Mistake was at $\log_{3}9x^2=4$** solution shown below

Confused on this question, not sure what I did wrong here.

$$\boxed{\log_{3}9x+\log_{3}x=4}$$
$$\log_{3}9x+\log_{3}x=4$$
$$\log_{3}9x\cdot x=4$$
$$\log_{3}9x^2=4$$
$$\dfrac{2\log_{3}9x=4}{2}$$
$$\log_{3}9x=2$$
$$3^2=9x$$
$$9=9x$$
$$x=1$$

---

$$\log_{3}9x^2=4$$

$$3^4=9x^2$$
$$\dfrac{81=9x^2}{9}$$
$$\sqrt{x^2=9}$$
$$\boxed{x=3, x\ne-3}$$

Comment: $\log_{3}9x^2=\log_{3}(3x)^2=2\log_{3}3x$

Comment: $(9x^2) \neq (9x)^2$, rather $(9x^2) = (3x)^2$.

Answer (score 6):

The error is when you go from $\log_3 9x^2 = 4$ to $\log_3 9x = 2$. Since $9x^2 = (3x)^2$, you should be writing $\log_3 3x = 2$ instead. Then proceed as before.

Comment: Okay, so in other words, the 9x divides by the $\log_{3}$ to give us 3?

Comment: If you're asking whether the answer is $x=3$, then yes, it is. =)

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach

$\log_{3}9x+\log_{3}x=4\iff \log_39+\log_3x+\log_3x=4\iff 2+2\log_3x=4\iff$

$\iff 2\log_3x=2\iff \log_3x=1\iff x=3$